# Retrieve value from input field, inside table TD when selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I am wondering if there is some way to retrieve a value from an input field, inside a TD when this TD is being selected (clicked).

I managed to get 1 of the values out, but it didn't change when I pressed the other row.

for example, here is my JSP, which leads to 2 TD's :

```
               <div class="col-md-6">
                        <table class="table fixed">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Choose what account you want to login to</th>
                                    <td align="right"><strong></strong></td>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="${roleList.getSize() -1}">
                                <tbody id="extend">
                                    <tr data-toggle="collapse123" class="clickableRow spaceUnder" nowrap="true" data-target=".demo1" id="1">
                                        <td class="AlignLeft" nowrap="true" style="border-right: 0px;">
                                            <label for="important"style="display: inline !important">${roleList.getFirstName(i)} ${roleList.getLastName(i)}</label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="right" class="AlignRight" style="border-left: 0px;">
                                            <input type="hidden" id ="roleId" name="chosenRole" value="${roleList.getClientId(i)}">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr> 
                                </c:forEach>

                        </table>
                        <input type="hidden" id ="roleClicked" name="roleClicked" value="">
                    </div>
```

And here is my javascript/jquery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

            $("#extend td").click(function () {
```

> How do i select the clicked TD's inputfield's value??

```
                $("#roleClicked").text();
            });
    });
```

> Edit: I'm Back was correct, although I had to move my input field from the second TD to the first one which is no problem at all for me (its hidden anyways)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Check this link](https://jsfiddle.net/abm05172/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
$('#extend td').click(function(){
    var roleid = $(this).find('input').val();
    $("#roleClicked").val(roleid);
});
});
```

Instead of  - The val() method returns or sets the value attribute of the selected elements.

```
$("#roleClicked").text();
```

Comment: Okey thank you, i did this now  `$("#roleClicked").val($("#roleId").val());` but now i get the same ID even though im clicking different TD's, how do i get the ID from the selected one? :)

Comment: I hope updated answer will help you check the fiddle link :) @MarcusH

Answer (score 0):

Solution should be this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

            $("#extend td").click(function () {
                $("#roleClicked").val($(this).find("input").val());
            });
    });
```

OR for ajax based loading.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#extend" ).on( "click", "td", function() {
        $("#roleClicked").val($(this).find("input").val());
    });
});
```

Comment: This did not work, but it feels closer to the solution since you are using (this), any other ideas? thank you for helping

Comment: you need to fill value of clicked input field into #roleClicke hidden field right?

Comment: Well yes, but im not clicking the input field. Im clicking the TD, which contains an input field, and then I want to fill the value into #roleClicked, yes

Comment: Then I am sure this code must should be work, are you loading this table content through ajax? if yes then need to use on('click',....) method.

Comment: I am not using ajax, maybe i will later on when i get to submitting the data

Comment: please check, I am 100% sure one of both should be worked. Thanks

Comment: Yes, the first one works (if i move the input field to the first td) thank you for helping :)